# How do I get a ‘Yes/No’ attribute to be only shown if it’s ‘Yes’ in a multilanguage store

Tags: magento, attributes, product

I would like to hide all the yes/no attributes on product page if they are 'no'. Things like 
`if($attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($product) == 'Yes')` don't work because I have a multilanguage shop.

Has anybody an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the attribute value for boolean attributes :

```
if (($attribute->getFrontendInput() != 'boolean')
    || $object->getData($this->getAttribute()->getAttributeCode())) {
    // Value can be displayed
}
```

Comment: Thank's for the answer. With `$attribute->getFrontendInput() != 'boolean'` I can only hide ALL Yes/No Attributes but I want to hide only the Yes/No-Attributes with 'no'-Value. Or did I missunderstood you?

Comment: Yes, in fact my code displays all values for attributes which are not boolean, and only `Yes` values otherwise (the `getData` call should return `1` for `Yes` and `0` for `No`)

Answer (score -2):

The **Yes/No** Attribute will have the value **1/0**. You can always check for this value from the front-end. The **Yes/No** attribute option code looks something like below:

```
<option value="1">Yes</option>
<option selected="selected" value="0">No</option>
```